# SQL Server having OLEDB waits on local view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019

I have some SQL Server views compiled as follows, some of them brings a large amount of data and causes OLEDB wait type, like if this it's being accessed from another instance.

```
CREATE VIEW [schema].[view_name] 
AS
    SELECT (...) 
    FROM [instance].[database].[schema].table
```

Is this a instance's parameter I can set to work without running the VIEW like it was a linked server? We're currently working on SQL Server 2016 and 2019, both return the same results.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify the view's definition.  Linked server tables use 4-part names Instance.Database.Schema.Table.  Three-part names are Database.Schema.Table and won't use linked server.

Comment: Hi David! Recreating the view using Database.Schema.Table stops SQL Server to act like it was using linked server. So in that case, even without a created linked server, if I use 4-part names in my views SQL Server will treat it as a linked server? Thanks!

Comment: Where is this table? In the same database? If so, why use 4 *or* 3? Use 2 part. Only use the smallest number of parts you actually need or 2, which ever is greater.

Comment: This table resides in another database, same instance. It's possible to work with 3 parts on this case. About my question using 4-part names, does SQL Server always acts like this? Thanks!

Comment: By using 4 part naming yes, you are explicitly stating to use the linked ever tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use 4-part names in my views SQL Server will treat it as a linked server?

Yes.  And that's a bad thing.  So don't do that.  Always use 3-part names to refer to objects other databases in the same instance, and 2-part names to refer to objects in the same database.

Comment: Now I'm using 3-part names and I understand how it works.Thank you very much, David!